# Local variables in rdired?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

Using ESS for running R inside emacs I can see values of variables in a rdired-buffer. This is only global variables, is there any way to browse local variables (that are set inside "user-written" functions)?

Comment: When you say "**that are set inside a function**", we all want to know **what function?**.  If you know the name of the function, type `M-x find-function`.  If you only know the keyboard shortcut or the menu-item, type `M-x describe-key` to find out the function name.  If you want to customize variables in a particular library, you can type `M-x customize-group`.  If you want to read the source-code of a particular library, you can type `M-x find-library.`  [This particular forum is really tough on people who do not have a specific programming question, so provide more details please.]

Comment: The tags for `r`, `scope`, and `ess` may potentially elicit responses from people unfamiliar with Emacs and could lead to unwarranted downvotes or votes-to-close without providing any constructive criticism.

Comment: Edited **functions** to **"user-written" functions**. Maybe you are overlooking the mentioning of rdired? This question has everything to do with `ESS` and `R`, but I removed `scope`. `rdired` does not exist.

Comment: The library `ess-rdired.el` is apparently missing a `(provide 'ess-rdired)` statement at the bottom, so you will not be able to use `M-x find-library`.  If you know where it is installed, you can manually browse the directory and open the file to see what makes it tick.  Here is the link to the source-code on Github:  https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/master/lisp/ess-rdired.el  The ESS manual doesn't say much about `rdired`, but you may wish to take a look at it:  http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html  Sorry that I could not be of more assistance.